# Set value of property if value is in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my main array:

```
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Saab', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'cStatus', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'BMW', flag: false},
    {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];

var cars1 = ["Saab", "Bmw"];
```

I am trying to set property `flag` to true of `myArray` objects, whose `field` property is included in the `cars1` variable.

Expected output in `myArray` variable only:

```
myArray = [
    {field: 'Saab', flag: true}, 
    {field: 'Volvo', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'BMW', flag: true},
    {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];
```

Can anybody please show me how to do this? I've tried the following:

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Saab', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'Volvo', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'BMW', flag: false},
    {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];
var cars1 = ["Saab", "BMW"]; 

console.log(myArray.filter(x => cars1.indexOf(x.field) > -1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the array and check if `cars1` contains `field`:

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Saab', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'Volvo', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'BMW', flag: false},
    {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];
var cars1 = ["Saab", "BMW"]; 

myArray.forEach(car => car.flag = cars1.indexOf(car.field) > -1);
console.log(myArray);
```

The above iterates over the array and `car` represents the current object. Then we assign `car.flag` to the result of `cars1.indexOf(car.field) > -1`. The result will be true if `cars1` contains the field, and false if it does not.

You can also use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the array includes a certain value, though it's not supported on all browsers (most do). This will get rid of the `indexOf` check:

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'Saab', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'Volvo', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'BMW', flag: false},
    {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];
var cars1 = ["Saab", "BMW"]; 

myArray.forEach(car => car.flag = cars1.includes(car.field));
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: This worked.thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: According to you includes doenst work in which browser?

Comment: @Learning Internet Explorer currently does not support it but all other major browsers do.

Comment: Internet explorer older versions or newser versions too doenst support??

Comment: @Learning To my knowledge, no IE versions support it. You can see [the browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) for `includes`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways how to solve it, is to use `Array#some` to check if specified element from the `myArray` exists in the `cars1` array. If it does - set `flag` to true.

```js
var myArray=[{field:"Saab",flag:false},{field:"cStatus",flag:false},{field:"BMW",flag:false},{field:"Mercedes",flag:false}],
    cars1 = ["Saab", "BMW"]; 

    myArray.forEach(v => cars1.some(c => c == v.field ? v.flag = true : null));
    console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I'm curious, is `some` needed here? It just seems a bit of an overcomplication.

Comment: @AndrewLi It's just one of the many ways how to fix it. And tbh I pretty like it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey Learning you can use the forEach method to loop through your 'myArray' and then use the .find method on cars1 for each iteration through your array.  If cars1.find, finds a that equals the current cars field, then it will set that value.flag to true.  If it does not, it will set it to false.

Here is a link to the 
.find() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

I hope this helps!

```
var myArray = [
  {field: 'Saab', flag: false}, 
  {field: 'Volvo', flag: false}, 
  {field: 'BMW', flag: false},
  {field: 'Mercedes', flag: false}
];

var cars1 = ["Saab", "BMW"]; 

myArray.forEach(value => {
  cars1.find((v) => v === value.field) ? value.flag = true : value.flag = false;
})
```

Comment: Hey Andrew thank you for the feedback.  I ran the code with the snippet that you provided and it did not work.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/uq31s8fv/ - also you could get rid of the parentheses, as they're redudant. I made a mistake in my comment, I meant `value.flag` not `v.flag`. Whoops

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for the explanation too and for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the cars and iterate then only `myArray`.

The key part is a callback which uses a closure over a set with the content of `cars1`

```
myArray.forEach(
    (cars => o => cars.has(o.field) && (o.flag = true))(new Set(cars1))
);
```

which basically is in the first step

```
    (cars => o => cars.has(o.field) && (o.flag = true))(new Set(cars1))
    (cars =>                                          )(new Set(cars1))
//   ^^^^                                                               closure over
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  set with car values
```

Inside of the returned function a check is made, if `field` is in the set and then the assignment of `true` to `o.flag` takes place.

```
             o => cars.has(o.field) && (o.flag = true)
//           ^                                          currentValue of array
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     check if field is in set
//                                  ^^                  if true
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  evaluate expression
//                                                      assign true to o.flag
```

```js
var myArray = [{ field: 'Saab', flag: false }, { field: 'cStatus', flag: false }, { field: 'BMW', flag: false }, { field: 'Mercedes', flag: false }],
    cars1 = ["Saab", "Bmw"];

myArray.forEach((cars => o => cars.has(o.field) && (o.flag = true))(new Set(cars1)));

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.can you please explain me this line :cars => o => cars.has(o.field) && (o.flag = true))(new Set(cars1))

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for the explanation too and for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)